# Fetch latest data in mysql query without using group by

Tags: mysql

Tables data are mentioned below

```
1 ABC aaaa
1 ABC bbbb
2 ABC aaaa
2 ABC bbbb
```

We want to fetch latest data such as

```
2 ABC aaaa
2 ABC bbbb
```

Please let me know what could be query for this data.

Comment: What does your schema look like? What have you already tried?

Comment: and what is it that makes those 2 lines the Latest Data

Comment: Need to fetch data of latest id  which means 2 is consider as last inserted id so need to fetch those data

Comment: `SELECT x,y FROM table WHERE x = (SELECT MAX(x) FROM table);`

Comment: Not sure what group by would have done for you in this case

Answer (score 0):

If your table has a field named `ID` which grows with each group of records (1, 2, ..) as in you example then you can use :

```
SELECT @Id := ID from table_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;  
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ID=@Id;
```

ID field must be indexed for better performance.